# textbox visual control how to get text

Tags: 2007, development, web-part

i have a user control, which has update panel and a button in it, when i click on button a message box appears, in messagebox i have one text box and another button,

when i click on another button, update panel triggers code behind method, now in my user control i need 2 get textbox text but no working

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
```

in usercontrol i am trying to ;

```
textbox1.text
```

but it is always empty

now in button click it is this'

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string button1text = TextBox1Text;
```

also added this,

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get 
        {
            return Page.Session["TextBox1Text"] as string;  
        }
        set
        {
            Page.Session["TextBox1Text"] = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for usercontrol only!

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get 
        {
            return Page.Session["TextBox1Text"] as string;  
        }
        set
        {
            Page.Session["TextBox1Text"] = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

the above is fine! you now need to put value into it when you click the button!

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //save value to session state
     TextBox1Text = textbox1.Text;
}
```

now within your onload function you can reload the value!

```
 if(!Page.IsPostback)
 if (TextBox1Text != null)
 {
    //get value from the session state!
    textbox1.Text = TextBox1Text;
 }
```

Comment: I have purged all comments. If you feel like chatting to each other we have a chat forum right here where you can discuss things further: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint